# OpenVPN TLS Error

Tags: ssl, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to connect to a VPN with openvpn (from my mac), however I receive the following error:

```
2021-02-18 15:30:42 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
2021-02-18 15:30:42 WARNING: normally if you use --mssfix and/or --fragment, you should also set --tun-mtu 1500 (currently it is 1079)
2021-02-18 15:30:42 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443
2021-02-18 15:30:42 UDP link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
2021-02-18 15:30:42 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443
2021-02-18 15:30:42 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
2021-02-18 15:31:42 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2021-02-18 15:31:42 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2021-02-18 15:31:42 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
```

client config

```
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 443 udp
auth-user-pass
ca [inline]
cert [inline]
key [inline]
tls-auth [inline] 1
link-mtu 1200
<certificates, keys, tls>
 key-direction 1
```

I saw similar posts, but they didnt really help me. I obfuscated the IP address in the log, but they are the same.

Comment: Shouldn't your remote port be 1194 rather than 443?

Answer (score 1):

1. Is your openVpn up and running?

   `sudo systemctl status openvpn` (for checking openvpn status on openvpn server)

   `sudo systemctl start openvpn`  (for starting openvpn service on server)
2. A perimeter firewall on the server’s network is filtering out incoming OpenVPN packets
   (by default OpenVPN uses UDP or TCP port number 1194).
3. A software firewall running on the OpenVPN server machine itself is filtering incoming
   connections on port 1194. Be aware that many OSes will block incoming connections by
   default, unless configured otherwise.
4. A NAT gateway on the server’s network does not have a port forward rule for TCP/UDP
   1194 to the internal address of the OpenVPN server machine.
5. The OpenVPN client config does not have the correct server address in its config file.
   The remote directive in the client config file must point to either the server itself
   or the public IP address of the server network’s gateway.
6. Another possible cause is that the windows firewall is blocking access for the
   openvpn.exe binary. You may need to whitelist (add it to the “Exceptions” list) it for
   OpenVPN to work.

Reffering to official openVPN resource: https://openvpn.net/faq/tls-error-tls-key-negotiation-failed-to-occur-within-60-seconds-check-your-network-connectivity/

I hope it helps you

Comment: it must be pretty much on the client side, because its working for my colleagues. the only point from that list as far as i understand regarding the client side would be the firewall. i even disabled it, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: Even the point 5 in the list... your client config file has ip, port and protocol correct?

Comment: yes that should be correct and i can also connect to it with nc -uvz